# What graphs have tree decompositions where the bags containing a vertex all lie on a path?

Tags: graph-theory, trees

My question is about [tree decompositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_decomposition) of graphs.

For the unfamiliar, the [tree decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_decomposition) of a graph $G$ is a tree $T$, where each vertex in $T$ (which are called bags) 'contains' vertices from the graph $G$. There are three defining properties as well:

1. Every vertex in $G$ is in a bag in $T$;
2. Every edge $vw$ from $G$ is contained (i.e. the vertices occur together) in at least one bag; and lastly
3. The bag subgraph containing a vertex $v$ is connected.

Tree decompositions are used to define a useful quantity: the [treewidth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treewidth) of a graph. This is just the smallest you can make the size of the maximal sized bag in any tree decomposition of that graph.

My question is about restricting the shapes of the bag subgraphs which contain a vertex. These must always be a tree, as the bags are connected and $T$ is a tree.

However, what happens if all bag subgraphs for the vertices must be *paths*:

1. Are there some graphs which don't have such decompositions?
2. Where there is such a decomposition, is the treewidth on the restricted type of decomposition ever strictly greater than the normal treewidth?
3. Does this subtype of tree decompositions have a name? Have they been studied by anyone?

---

Answers so far:

1. No, throw everything into the same bag.

[image: (Here's an example of such a graph from Wikipedia.] [link](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Tree_decomposition.svg))

Comment: The trivial tree decomposition comprising one bag containing all vertices always trivially satisfies your path subgraph requirement, unless you add some conditions to eliminate such trivial solutions.

Comment: ~Ah, you're right; I should have specified with minimum width. I'll edit that now.~

Comment: Actually, the above restriction doesn't make any sense for what I was asking. Thus 1 is answered: yes, using the trivial tree decomposition.